# Mouse integration logitech wireless on virtualbox for select, cut and paste

Tags: virtualbox, mouse

I've installed virtualbox and an appliance from bitnami "common-postgresql-16-16.2.0-r1-debia-11-amd64" image installed. I'm using a logitech wireless keyboard and mouse on my Intel I7 ASUS with Nvidia Geforce GTX. When I launch the VM it fails to capture the mouse stating "The Virtual Machine reports that the guest OS does not support mouse pointer integration in the current video mode. You need to capture the mous (by clicking over the VM display or pressing the host key) in order to use the mouse inside the guest OS."

But when I click in the window the mouse disappears. I can move the mouse outside the window and it reappears. On another system I have a similar problem, but have to hit the right ctrl key to get it back each time. Either way, I don't get a mouse cursor to enable me to select and copy text from the terminal window, nor can I right click to paste anything.

I've tried all the settings of the mouse, including 'tablet', tried WMSVGA graphics controller setting, and even tried to add USB 'filters' without success. I have cut&paste and drag&drop set to bi-directional. It also disables my logitech keyboard and mouse and I have to use the laptop's.

What can I do to get mouse select, cut and paste between the terminal window and my laptop to work?

Comment: It's an issue with the VM or Virtualbox. It has nothing to do with the host OS. Mucking about drivers properly installed in the host will do nothing and can make it worse. You may need to install guest additions in the VM.

Comment: And, needless to say, brand/model is irrelevant here.